# DateDiff use current date if enddate is null

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I am calculating two dates and returning days but want to exclude weekends and holidays. I also want to say, if the enddate is null, then use the current date?

How do I do that with datediff?

Comment: Search for answers where it says how to calculate business days in SQL. For second part you can use `IF` or `CASE` statement to change NULL to current date.

Comment: ISNULL(EndDate, GETDATE())

Comment: You can't calculate holidays with SQL Server. You need to write your own logic. For weekends, use `DATEPART(DW, <your date>)` - it will return 0 for Sunday and 7 for Saturday, assuming that's the weekend where you are. To substitute for a null value, look up the `COALESCE` function.

Comment: Post what you have tried so far. Just for clarify @EdGibbs: `DATEPART` function will return day from 1 to 7, if sunday it returns 1 not 0.

Comment: Thanks @alejandrozuleta; you're correct - brain fart on my part :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Or use this..

```
if object_id('tempdb..#Holidays') is not null drop table temp..#Holidays
create table #Holidays(id int identity(1,1),Holiday date)
insert into #Holidays values ('2015-12-25'),('2015-12-28')
set dateformat ymd
declare @StartDate date = '2015-12-01'
declare @EndtDate date = '2015-12-31'
--some times @EndtDate might be NULL so, set to getdate()
set @EndtDate = isnull(@EndtDate,cast(getdate() as date))

declare @Holiday int 
set @Holiday = (select count(*) from #Holidays where Holiday between @StartDate and @EndtDate)

SELECT
   (DATEDIFF(dd, @StartDate, @EndtDate) + 1)
  -(DATEDIFF(wk, @StartDate, @EndtDate) * 2)
  -(CASE WHEN DATENAME(dw, @StartDate) = 'Sunday' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)
  -(CASE WHEN DATENAME(dw, @EndtDate) = 'Saturday' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)
  -@Holiday
```